# How to set Content-Type for IE in Perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a webpage in Perl.  I write out the Content Type with this line at the beginning of the script:

```
print header('Content-Type' => 'text/HTML');
```

This work in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE, it still try to download the page as a file.  What should I do to also make IE work?

Comment: mime types are lower case. `text/html`, not `text/HTML`

Comment: Didn't make any difference.  It already work in Chrome/Firefox so I think the mime type is case-insensitive.

Comment: @MarcB From [RFC 1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html): "In the Extended BNF notation of RFC 822, a Content-Type header field value is defined as follows: `Content-Type := type "/" subtype *[";" parameter]"` [...] The type, subtype, and parameter names are not case sensitive. For example, TEXT, Text, and TeXt are all equivalent."

Comment: Please report the full response header you send, because there might be other problems (like setting content-disposition).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I used fiddle and found that the content-type was not set correctly.  I have fixed it now, will post answer.

Comment: That produces completely invalid headers. I guess that Chrome and Firefox are being rather more lax about headers than IE is. But 'text/html' is the default content-type that `header()` sets, so just remove all of the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the generated headers by running on the command line:

```
perl -MCGI=:standard -we 'print header( q{Content-Type} => q{text/html} )'
```

Outputs:

```
Status: text/html
Content-Type: Content-Type; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

This is obviously not what you want. There are [several ways to pass parameters](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#CREATING-A-STANDARD-HTTP-HEADER:) to the `header` function. You are calling it like this:

```
header($content_type, $status);
```

If you want to call `header` with named parameters, you have to prefix them with a dash. Anything other than the recognized parameters `-type`, `-status`, `-expires`, and `-cookie` will be stripped of the initial dash and converted to a header, so both of the following work:

```
perl -MCGI=:standard -we 'print header( q{-Content-Type} => q{text/html} )'

perl -MCGI=:standard -we 'print header( q{-type} => q{text/html} )'
```

Outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

However, `text/html` is the default value for `Content-Type`, so you don't need to specify the `Content-Type` at all:

```
perl -MCGI=:standard -we 'print header()'
```

Outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 3):

The CGI documentation shows just `-type` as the key for Content-Type in `header`. If it's the only argument, you can omit it and only specify the value.

```
header( -type => 'text/html' );

# or even

header('text/html');
```

Comment: Or even just `header()` ('text/html' is the default content type).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the line to:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
```

Not sure why the original didn't work, but anyways.

Comment: It didn't work because you weren't following the documentation :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use CGI.pm.
CGI::header does not set a single header, but sets the full HTTP header.
From the documentation/examples of header:

```
      print header('text/plain');
```

I think you confused CGI::header with a similar named function in PHP. But same name does not mean same functionality.